# notification intent not received by activity

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am working on an Android app. There are activities A and B. Activity A launches activity B. There is a background service generating notifications. Notification intent has some extra data that has to be received by the activity.

When the app is fully stopped and the notification pressed - activity A is started and it receives the intent from the notification, with the extra data **(correct)**.

When the app is paused/suspended in activity B and the notification pressed - activity B `getIntent()` (called from `onResume()`) returns the original intent made by activity A when starting activity B and **not the intent made by the notification**.

How do I receive the notification intent in activity started from another activity?

This is the code that makes the notification:

```
Intent intent = this.mContext.getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(this.mContext.getPackageName())
                .setPackage(null)
                .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED)
                .putExtra("extra_data", extra);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
    PendingIntent.getActivity(this.mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Notification n = mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();
n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; //remove notification when pressed

mNotificationManager.notify((int)((new Date().getTime() / 1000L) % Integer.MAX_VALUE), n);
```

Comment: Why would B receive the intent? If it was A then it will be A again.

Comment: When app is paused in activity B, I press the notification then activity B is resumed, so I would expect it to receive the intent, not activity A to be relaunched.

Comment: I think A is resumed but with it on top B.

Comment: Even with android:launchMode="singleTop" in the manifest?

Comment: This one gets it: `.getLaunchIntentForPackage(this.mContext.getPackageName())`. Its always the same.

Comment: I see..... I think that it is the problem.

Comment: Intent intent = new  Intent(mContext, YourActivityNameToBeLaunch.class)

Comment: try to catch intent data in onNewIntent/onCreate method in your activity